# Store array data in a file on Java 9 text output/input

Tags: java, arrays, java-9

I just started learning how to write into file and read from a file on java oi. Now I can write simple text into a file and also can read it using system.out.print. The problem now is, I tried to create an array and store it in a file using the same  way I learnt, but when I run the program the file is created but there was nothing to display. Please is there any thing I can do otherwise, below is the sample of my codes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File Veggies= new File ("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\My Java Files\\Product.txt");
    if(Veggies.exists())
        System.exit(0);     

    PrintWriter output= new  PrintWriter(Veggies);
    output.println("These are the list of our products.");


    String[] VeggiesArray={"Apples","Bananas","Oranges","Avocados","Strawberries"};
    for(int i=0;i<=VeggiesArray.length;i++){
        output.println("(" + i + ")" +" "+ VeggiesArray[i]);
    }

    output.close();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Veggies.exists()? I believe that will exit immediately after creating the file.

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions : packages, attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in **lowerCase**, while class, interface should start in **UpperCase**

Comment: You're likely going to run into a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` with `i<=VeggiesArray.length`, as arrays are `0` indexed, meaning the statement should read more like `i < VeggiesArray.length`

Answer (score 0):

```
    File veggies= new File (".\\Product.txt"); 

    PrintWriter output= new PrintWriter(veggies); 
    output.println("These are the list of our products."); 

    String[] veggiesArray={"Apples","Bananas","Oranges","Avocados","Strawberries"}; 
    for(int i=0;(i<veggiesArray.length);i++) { 
        output.println("(" + i + ")" +" "+ veggiesArray[i]); 
    } 
    output.close();
```

Got rid of the veggies.Exists() because it would only allow you to generate the file one time, without first deleting it.

Fixed the loop condition as MadProgrammer pointed out.

Comment: Instead of `(i<=veggiesArray.length -1)`, just use `i<veggiesArray.length`.